# How to use substitute character (^Z) in XML?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

How can I use ASCII 26 in XML?

When I'm using `&#26;` I got character reference `&#26;` is an invalid XML character.

Comment: Alternatives: Take text, encode with an agreed upon character encoding (say UTF-8); take resulting bytes, encode with agreed upon Base64 or hex. Or, use JSON instead of XML. For XML with UTF-8 and Base64, you could internally document the scheme as a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

Answer (score 2):

**You don't.**

Decimal `26` (`0x1A`aka `^Z` aka `SUB` aka *substitute*) is ***not an [allowed character in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets)*** :

> ```
> [2] Char ::= #x9|#xA|#xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
> ```

Therefore your data is not XML, and any conformant XML processor must report an error such as the one you received.

You must repair the data by removing any illegal characters by treating it as ***text, not XML,*** manually or automatically before using it with any XML libraries.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII 26 is what is known as the [substitute character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character). In Unicode, it is [represented as U+001a](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/001a/index.htm)

Try:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Test>&#26;</Test>
```

You can verify that with the following C#

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Test>&#26;</Test>");

var substituteCharacter = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//Test").InnerText;
// substituteCharacter is "\u001a"
```

or

```
xmlDocument.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Test>&#x1A;</Test>");
```

Comment: I guess it's because C# functions handle this particularly